# Minio with the iOS AWS S3 SDK SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I have an iOS app that uploads / downloads to / from Amazon's S3.  I'd like to replace Amazon's S3 with my own Minio cloud.

I followed the quick tutorial here https://github.com/minio/minio and I have Minio running on my localhost and I can put files using s3cmd (https://docs.minio.io/docs/s3cmd-with-minio).

Unfortunately I can't manage to get it to work from within my iOS app.

I'm using the AWS SDK v2.4.16 so I can change the endpoint and I made it my localhost (http://my-imac.local:9000) and I updated my access and secret keys but I get a SignatureDoesNotMatch error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.".

Pointing to my local server:

```
AWSEndpoint *minioEndpoint = [[AWSEndpoint alloc] initWithURLString:@"http://my-imac.local:9000"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:region 
        endpoint:minioEndpoint 
        credentialsProvider:credentialProvider];
[AWSS3 registerS3WithConfiguration:configuration forKey:s3RegionString];
```

Here's what I get on my localhost:

> time="2017-04-10T23:36:21Z" level=error
>   msg="{\"method\":\"PUT\",\"path\":\"/mybucket/28AB7D6DCFC44102955EBC0AEFF6E4E2-20170407161228839-0700/foo_28AB7D6DCFC44102955EBC0AEFF6E4E2-20170407161228839-0700_v2.json_bin\",\"query\":\"\",\"header\":{\"Accept\":[\"*/*\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip,
>   deflate\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-us\"],\"Authorization\":[\"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
>   Credential=LNTXV0YMMZ9SY7MD0ACZ/20170410/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,
>   SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date,
>   Signature=7b2f4172dd926ba84c7edba5170028e0f9361bd8a656ad8f01c7e232f585ab31\"],\"Connection\":[\"keep-alive\"],\"Content-Length\":[\"282416\"],\"Content-Type\":[\"application/octet-stream\"],\"Host\":[\"my-imac.local\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"aws-sdk-iOS/2.4.16
>   iPhone-OS/9.1 en_US\"],\"X-Amz-Date\":[\"20170410T233620Z\"]}}"
>   cause="Signature does not match"
>   source="[object-handlers.go:472:objectAPIHandlers.PutObjectHandler()]"

On the iOS side:

The request headers are:

```
{
    Authorization = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=LNTXV0YMMZ9SY7MD0ACZ/20170410/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date, Signature=454c8bad35bdd3a15a08c9bf555fc69f1d5c0dabad78a474eabd4d844ca69aef";
    "Content-Length" = 282416;
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
    Host = "my-imac.local";
    "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.4.16 iPhone-OS/9.1 en_US";
    "X-Amz-Date" = 20170410T233622Z;
}
```

The response:

```
2017-04-10 16:36:22.507 demo[7969:4711709] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.16 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:566 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersForResponse:] | Response headers:
{
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    Date = "Mon, 10 Apr 2017 23:36:22 GMT";
    Server = "Minio/RELEASE.2017-03-16T21-50-32Z (linux; amd64)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = Origin;
    "X-Amz-Request-Id" = 14B42D7AE5B09A2B;
}
```

Comment: Hey can you please check https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/4039#issuecomment-293787123  and let us know if this solves the issue you are facing?

Comment: @koolhead17 : yes that's it!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace `accessKey`, `secretKey`, and `url`, change the region base on what you need, service must set to `.S3`

(`AWSS3` will auto remove port number if you type `xxxx:9000` in `url`, currently it only support full url without port, so please make sure you have a domain map to port 9000, you may need refer to this [Setup Nginx proxy with Minio Server](https://docs.minio.io/docs/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio))

```
let accessKey = "XXXXXXX"
let secretKey = "XXXXXXX"

let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, endpoint: AWSEndpoint(region: .USEast1, service: .S3, url: URL(string:"XXXXXX")),credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let S3BucketName = "images"
let remoteName = "test.jpg"
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(remoteName)
let image = UIImage(named: "test")
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.9)
do {
    try data?.write(to: fileURL)
}
catch {}

let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
uploadRequest.body = fileURL
uploadRequest.key = remoteName
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpeg"
uploadRequest.acl = .publicRead

let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith { (task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
  ...
}
```

[Full example project here](https://github.com/atom2ueki/minio-ios-example)

NOTE you need to apply the following change as well to make it fully work https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/pull/638

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet your trying to use user credentials instead of a service account.

From the web UI, take a look at the user and create a service account which makes a new "access key" and "secret key" associated with this user.

Those credentials should do the trick.
(or at-least that's what worked for me.)

I was using a really old version of minio and updated to a 2023 release and wow its really different in a good way.